# How can I get an if statement to remember a value as it executes?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I've got a semi-working decision loop in python working but need a pointer to get it working 100%.

I have a couple of stock tickers I update the value of every 'x' minutes and display the value on a Raspberry Pi LCD. What I've tried to do, and fail, is get the backlight to change to red when one of the stock falls, it works fine if both are negative and if the last is negative but if the first is negative and second positive values it doesn't work. How can I make this work ?

```
tickersymbols = ['ticker1', 'ticker2']

i = 0
while (i <  3):
    lcd.clear()
    for tickerSymbol in tickersymbols:

            allInfo = ystockquote.get_all(tickerSymbol)

            price = float(allInfo["price"])

            change = float(allInfo["change"])
            if change >= 0:
                    backlight.rgb(0,255,0)
                    lcd.write(tickerSymbol + "= %+3.2f (%+0.2f)" % (price, change))
            else:
                    backlight.rgb(255,0,0)
                    lcd.write(tickerSymbol + "= %+3.2f (%+0.2f)" % (price, change))
```

Comment: 1] Instead of using while-loop to update every x-minutes, look into ``time.sleep`` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep). 2] Your question doesn't quite sense, as you are unclear to which if-statement you are referring to. 3] Try to debug by printing to console (i.e. use ``print``-command) instead of ``icd`` to figure where the problem is.

Comment: MrGrumble - the while loop is just a temporary thing so I can loop thru' a few times so I don't miss the display and as you correctly point out I do actually time.sleep a bit further down in the code. The actual error as far as I can see is the if/else changes the backlight to red only if the second ticker is a negative value, what I want to achieve is if either or both are negative I want the backlight as red - if that makes a bit more sense ? - Novice coder as you can tell :)

Comment: @northwarks Is my answer what you are looking for, or do you want to `break` out of your code upon a negative value as the other answers suggest?

Comment: @Elizon - I need to stay in the if statement until I have both values as I display both on screen +ve or -ve

Comment: @northwarks Then try implementing my answer, I don't see why it wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking more closely at your problem, **you do NOT want to break from the for loop**. That will cause you to miss the lcd.write() statements for the remaining tickerSymbols.

Instead, you just want to set a flag if you see the price go down. Then, after the loop, change the color of the LED according to the flag.

```
tickersymbols = ['ticker1', 'ticker2']

i = 0
while (i <  3):
    lcd.clear()
    stockWentDown=False
    for tickerSymbol in tickersymbols:
        allInfo = ystockquote.get_all(tickerSymbol)
        price = float(allInfo["price"])
        change = float(allInfo["change"])
        lcd.write(tickerSymbol+ "= %+3.2f (%+0.2f)" % (price, change))
        if change < 0:
            stockWentDown=True
    if not stockWentDown: #if the stock went up or stayed the same
        #color it green
        backlight.rgb(0,255,0)
    elif stockWentDown: #if the stock went down
        #color it red
        backlight.rgb(255,0,0)
```

Comment: Thanks for this - Not ignoring, overwhelmed with the response! Just testing the answers between phone calls and some stock values.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me; I don't have enough reputation to comment anywhere but here, hence the annoying text at the beginning of my post. Sorry about that! 

Let me know if my code works, and if it solves your problem then please don't forget to accept the code as the answer (so I can get enough reputation to do basic things, lol).

Comment: I've chosen this solution, it works but crucially as a newb at coding I've gained some additional knowledge using a boolean (?).  I've also noted some of the feedback re naming variables and will take that forward. As a first post I've been overwhelmed with the speed and number of responses so big thanks to all of the responses.

Comment: I'm thrilled I can help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments the easiest thing to do is set `backlight.rgb(0, 255, 0)` before the for loop and simply change to red if either `change` is < 0:

```
ticker_symbols = ['ticker1', 'ticker2']
while i < 3:
    lcd.clear()
    backlight.rgb(0, 255, 0) # reset normal background each time
    for ticker_symbol in ticker_symbols:
        all_info = ystockquote.get_all(ticker_symbol)
        price = float(all_symbol["price"])
        change = float(all_symbol["change"])    
        if change < 0: # only change to red when  we find any price drop          
            backlight.rgb(255, 0, 0)
        lcd.write(ticker_symbol + "= %+3.2f (%+0.2f)" % (price, change)) # always change display
```

It makes sense to always start with `backlight.rgb(0, 255, 0)` then change to red to notify of a price drop. Otherwise how would you know by looking at the screen whether the screen is red from a previous drop or the current.

Comment: But then won't he not hit all of the `lcd.write` statements if the first stock is negative?

Comment: @Elizion, that is the point.  The OP has stated that having a positive second value is overwriting the the first. If the OP wants the light to change twice then there code would not need to be changed. *What I've tried to do, and fail, is get the backlight to change to red when one of the stock falls,*

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused. Aren't the backlight color and the `lcd.write()` statements two separate things? I was under the impression that he wanted everything to remain the same save for the background color not turning red.

Comment: - I need to check/display both stocks, If either of the 2 stocks turns negative I want the LCD to turn red, currently the value of the final stock overrides so I'm missing stock 1 turning negative - HTH?

Comment: @northwarks, if you have two stocks and the second is positive you end up overwriting the previous display change. You need to break the for loop on finding any negative value.  If you want to write both changes to the lcd we need to modify the code

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham - But I still need to run thru' the if statement to get both values - So I want to: Go and get stock values, if any of the stock values have dropped i.e. -ve on the day I need to change the display to red (255,0,0), if all are up on the day i.e +ve then don't change the display colour just write them to the LCD. - HTH ?

Comment: @northwarks, so one write does not overwrite the other?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham - No it has 3 lines so doesn't over write at this stage. The code I've included essentially appends it to the display for now, no point in moving on until I can get this bit working as a newbie.

Comment: @northwarks, edited the answer, if you are only worried about changing to red forget the other rgb value in the for loop and just reset it outside the for each time

Comment: I also changed some of your variables to use underscores, is suggest when writing python code to do so for all your variables

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty rudimentary, but why not just add another conditional statement within your `if`, *(so long as your default color isn't red)*. This way your `for` loop will still continue to run, and you will still get all of the `lcd.write`'s that you do at this point.

```
tickersymbols = ['ticker1', 'ticker2']

i = 0
while (i <  3):
    lcd.clear()
    backlight.rgb(255,0,0)
    for tickerSymbol in tickersymbols:

            allInfo = ystockquote.get_all(tickerSymbol)

            price = float(allInfo["price"])

            change = float(allInfo["change"])
            if change < 0:
                backlight.rgb(0,255,0)

            lcd.write(tickerSymbol + "= %+3.2f (%+0.2f)" % (price, change))
```

Comment: This will always leave the background red if we get continuous negative price changes, also `backlight.rgb` is a method so `if backlight.rgb != (255,0,0)` is comparing a tuple to a method

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Edited for the method error, thanks. This look good now?

Comment: I would hope so as I took the same approach!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ah, I just noticed that. Have to love when you misunderstand the OP, I have an error in my code, and eventually we end up with the same solution.

Comment: There was a little ambiguity in the question but I think we have the correct and most efficient solution now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on you code, if the first change is negative and the second isn't you end up overwriting the display. Seems to me that all you have to do is **break** out of the while loop anytime the value is changed as highlighted by **Padraic Cunningham**. However if you want to maintain your configuration of running through the while loop twice, you can always set a flag

```
tickersymbols = ['ticker1', 'ticker2']

i = 0
flag=0
while (i <  3):
    lcd.clear()

    for tickerSymbol in tickersymbols:

            allInfo = ystockquote.get_all(tickerSymbol)

            price = float(allInfo["price"])

            change = float(allInfo["change"])
            if (change >= 0 && flag==0):
                    backlight.rgb(0,255,0)
                    lcd.write(tickerSymbol + "= %+3.2f (%+0.2f)" % (price, change))
            else:
                    backlight.rgb(255,0,0)
                    lcd.write(tickerSymbol + "= %+3.2f (%+0.2f)" % (price, change))
                    flag=1
```